# Appending a csv file to an array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, csv

```
def readtable(file, array):
    f = open(file)
    f.readline()
    for i in f:
        for j in i:
            array[i].append(j)

    readtable("DADSA RESIT CWK JULY 2018.csv", database)
```

I'm trying to scan a CSV file into an array in Python, but every time I execute this code I got the message:

```
"TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str".
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

If it helps, if I delete the penultimate line and just finish with "`array.append(i)`" the array scans just fine, but it prints each row as all one line. I want to be able to break them up into columns too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`csv.reader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader) from the standard library.

```
import csv

with open("DADSA RESIT CWK JULY 2018.csv", newline='') as f:
    r = csv.reader(f)
    l = list(r)
```